# magento table that stores relation between cms_block and categories

Tags: database, magento

In Magento, I need to run a query to find out which categories have a Static Block assigned.  I know static blocks are stored in `cms_block`, and also where categories are stored.  However, what is the table that joins these two in the database?  Or is it a foreign key field in the category table?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Categories are EAV model, so, you should indeed look at some table to join.
Here is the request you are looking for :

```
select cat.*, cms.* from `catalog_category_entity` as cat
    join `catalog_category_entity_int` as ci on cat.entity_id = ci.`entity_id`
    join `eav_attribute` as att on att.`attribute_id` = ci.`attribute_id`
    join `cms_block` as cms on cms.`block_id` = ci.`value`
    where att.`attribute_code` = 'landing_page'
```

Alan Storm, has a really great article (as usual) on his blog if you want to dig deeper into Magento EAV structure : http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1

Comment: very clever - so the EAV system can be used for many-to-many joins! I.e. the middle two tables function as the join table between cat and cms...

Comment: Note that I'd probably do this as a `join` vs. a `left join` as that would be more exclusionary and probably faster

Comment: @OliverWilliams well seen. Answer updated accordingly

Comment: And actually the EAV structure is not meant to be a many to many join table but rather intended to have models which can have an extensible number of attribute without having to alter table as far as sql is concerned. [More info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model)

Comment: Yes, but here it serves that purpose quite well ;)